# Win2003 reports an error on RDP login: Could not open a TCP/IP socket

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

We have a Win2003 sp2 server that reports the following error when you log into it via RDP--

'Could not initialize communication profile: TCP/IP.  Could not open a TCP/IP socket. Address already in use. The combination of IP address and receive port is in use by another program. Please edit the communication profile, click advanced and change either.'

This server is virtualized (VMWare ESXi).

No errors in the logs.

After logging in and closing the error, there are no other problems. Finally, what's a communications profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the "NetOp Remote Control" product? This looks suspiciously like an error being generated by a program that it runs on startup.

Comment: You're right. A SysAdmin finally got the auditing portion of Track-It! to 'work'. He didn't realize it was installing on servers. Thanks.